# order of inserted item messed up after update in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm developing a e-commerce platform using mongodb, as the timestamp is a a part of mongodb's auto generated id, I expect I don't have to get the items using sort or order by.

But that wasn't the case, I've done the insert and update part, so the order of the item is not consistent now. The later created item appear in the middle. Why does that happened?

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on internal ID calculation — its only purpose is to be unique, not sequential.

Common pattern in cases such as yours is to add a field `time` in your item, then [`createIndex()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) on the collection and sort items whenever you get them using `find()`.

Comment: so I should do a typical created_on && last_updated?

Comment: Yes, if you want to store both creation timestamp and last update timestamp.